# Java (Swing): MouseMoved not working at all

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

This is driving me nuts. It must be an extremely simple problem, but I can't possibly see it.

Basically mouseMoved is NEVER called. Below is the code.

```
public class MouseMotionThing {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
            jFrame.setContentPane(new ContentPane());
            jFrame.setSize(400, 400);
            jFrame.setVisible(true);
            jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }); 
}
}
```

And my panel. This implementation uses a MouseInputListener:

```
class ContentPane extends JPanel implements MouseInputListener {
int x = 0, y = 0;

public ContentPane() {
    setOpaque(true);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);

}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawLine(0, 0, x, y);
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Mouse Dragged!");
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("CALLED MOUSE MOVED");
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();

    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}
}
```

whereas this alternative implementation uses only a MouseMotionListener:

```
class ContentPane extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {
int x = 0, y = 0;

public ContentPane() {
    setOpaque(true);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);

}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawLine(0, 0, x, y);
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Mouse Dragged!");
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("CALLED MOUSE MOVED");
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();

    repaint();
}
}
```

In none of the above alternative implementations is mouseMoved EVER called. I'm adding the right listeners every single time, but it's simply not working. mouseDragged works fine though. What am I missing?

LE: I tested the code on Ubuntu 12.10 & JDK 7, worked fine. Then when I went back to my W8 machine, it started working. I did absolutely nothing more than restart my laptop. I couldn't reproduce the problem nor track it down, but I will come back if I get it again and manage to find something.

Comment: Either `ContentPane` works for me.

Comment: Yep, work for me too! Your code looks fine as well.

Comment: Does your JFrame have focus? Maybe try clicking on the panel and then moving around on it

Comment: Maybe some extra info help, e.g. JDK version, the operating system, the input type (a mouse?), etc.

Comment: @drewmore4: that doesn't matter. As long as the mouse is over the GUI and as long as nothing else on the GUI is stealing the mouse listener (such as an active glass pane), then the code will work.

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Tried both JDK 6 and 7, exact same effect; Windows 8; same effect both with mouse and touchpad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seemed that I had those problems when I used my A4TECH G10-770F mouse on Windows 8. If I turned it off, things went back to normal. I didn't look into it in greater detail though - I already had another mouse and used that one instead.

Comment: Too bad this is happening with my touchpad

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear where things may have gone awry; it may help to do a full build. For reference, I've re-factored your [sscce](http://sscce.org/) to use a `MouseAdapter` and remove a leaking `this` from the `JPanel`.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MouseMotionThing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
                jFrame.add(new MousePanel());
                jFrame.pack();
                jFrame.setSize(400, 400);
                jFrame.setVisible(true);
                jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }

    private static class MousePanel extends JPanel {

        Point p = new Point();

        public MousePanel() {
            setOpaque(true);
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseHandler());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawLine(0, 0, p.x, p.y);
        }

        private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                update(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                update(e);
            }

            private void update(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e.paramString());
                MousePanel.this.p = e.getPoint();
                MousePanel.this.repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The code looks (and is) perfectly fine, but I still have the same behavior: drag works, but mouseMoved is never called.

Comment: That has the ring of a stale class in the path. That's part of why I used nested and renamed classes. Any help from the build environment?

Comment: Tested OK on Windows 7 / JDK 7.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to come across a similar issue in one of the applications I contribute to. I couldn't find anything else that pointed to the root cause, so I started doing some Java AWT logging as illustrated on Oracle's [Logging Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html) page.

After analyzing parts of the file, I found that there were 5 mouse buttons being registered to the JVM:

```
<record>
    <date>2015-06-18T15:45:54</date>
    <millis>1434656754395</millis>
    <sequence>70</sequence>
    <logger>sun.awt.windows.WDesktopProperties</logger>
    <level>FINE</level>
    <class>sun.awt.windows.WDesktopProperties</class>
    <method>setIntegerProperty</method>
    <thread>1</thread>
    <message>awt.mouse.numButtons=5</message>
</record>
```

I also realized that other mouse events (`MOUSE_ENTERED`, `MOUSE_EXITED`, `MOUSE_DRAGGED`) had a `extModifiers` value of `Button5`, which is weird because I was just using a touch pad and no other button is pressed. I'm not sure if this would prevent the `MOUSE_MOVED` event from being fired - I'm guessing this would take some research into lower level Java.

```
<record>
    <date>2015-06-18T15:45:55</date>
    <millis>1434656755026</millis>
    <sequence>329</sequence>
    <logger>java.awt.event.EventDispatchThread</logger>
    <level>FINEST</level>
    <class>java.awt.EventDispatchThread</class>
    <method>pumpOneEventForFilters</method>
    <thread>13</thread>
    <message>Dispatching: java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_ENTERED,(388,387),absolute(388,387),button=0,extModifiers=Button5,clickCount=0] on frame0</message>
</record>
```

I did some research on extra mouse buttons and found another Oracle page talking about [Desktop Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/DesktopProperties.html). I changed the startup parameters of Java to include `-Dsun.awt.enableExtraMouseButtons=false`, and voila, my application started working again.

I tested a very simple Java application with listening to `MOUSE_MOVED` on a variety of Windows JRE's, and they all exhibited the same issue when not setting this parameter.

If extra mouse buttons aren't going to be used in your application, then this may be a workaround for you.